# Why ConcurrentModificationException occurs using putAll?

Tags: android, hashmap

Sometimes I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` while executing an `AsyncTask`.
I do not iterate through `mapA` or `mapB` and modify anything. `getThis` and `getThat` just return a `HashMap`.

```
Map<Integer, CustomObject> mapA = object.getThis();
Map<Integer, CustomObject> mapB = object.getThat();

mapA.putAll(mapB); <-- throws sometimes a ConcurrentModificationException
```

EDIT 1:

My object have multiple Methods which do modify my Hashmap like:

```
public void resetThis(){
        this.mThis = new HashMap<>();
    }

public void addToThis(Object o){
        this.mThis.put(o.getId(), o);
    }

public void removeFromThis(int ID){
        this.mThis.remove(ID);
    }
```

But that should not be a problem, because I have here a different reference. Here is the stack trace.

```
Process: myApp, PID: 10863
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:757)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:790)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:788)
        at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
        at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
        at model.ModelSqLite.save(ModelSqLite.java:579) <---------- here is mapA.putAll(mapB);
        at classes.save(xxx.java:646)
        at app.Activity$SaveTask.doInBackground(Activity.java:939)
        at app.Activity$SaveTask.doInBackground(Activity.java:924)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

EDIT 2:
In my Activity OnButton Click I do this (reduced everything to the essential) :

```
private void updateContentView(View ContentView, Foo oFoo) {

        Map<Integer, CustomObject> mapThis = oFoo.getThis());
        List<Integer> listIdsToDelete = oFoo.getListToDelete();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, CustomObject> entry : mapThis.entrySet()) {
            CustomObject o = entry.getValue();
            oFoo.add(o);
        }

        for (int iID : listIdsToDelete) {
            oFoo.removeThis(iID); <--- Modification here

            CustomObject o = oFoo.getCustomObjectByID(iID);
            oFoo.addRemainingObject(o);
        }
}
```

In my second for loop, I remove some keys from that HashMap.
At the same time I start my Background Task where the exception occurs.

Comment: Please update your question to show all the interactions you have with this HashMap

Comment: added additional information

Comment: Sorry but I still need to see more code, specifically where it is you are writing and reading to this map. Where are you calling `addToThis` and `removeFromThis`. Your stacktrace points to your "save" method in `ModelSqLite`, so you can start by adding that to your question.

Comment: sorry, look at Edit 2 please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> listIdsToDelete = oFoo.getListToDelete();
//...

for (int iID : listIdsToDelete) {
    oFoo.removeThis(iID); <--- Modification here
    CustomObject o = oFoo.getCustomObjectByID(iID);
    oFoo.addRemainingObject(o);
}
```

You're probably attempting to remove from this list whilst iterating it. You have a few techniques for solving this problem, but the most common (and backwards compatible) uses an iterator:

```
final Iterator<Integer> it = oFoo.getListToDelete().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    final int id = it.next();
    //Use id...
   it.remove();
}
```

You may also be able to make a copy of `oFoo.getListToDelete()` and iterate that instead:

```
List<Integer> listIdsToDelete = new ArrayList(oFoo.getListToDelete()); //copy
//...

for (int iID : listIdsToDelete) {
    oFoo.removeThis(iID); <--- Modification here
    CustomObject o = oFoo.getCustomObjectByID(iID);
    oFoo.addRemainingObject(o);
}
```